# Sending a text message without being prompted

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, imessage

I have seen only a couple of these questions online, all are from a few years back. I am attempting to make an app that will send a text to phone number you entered without having a pop-up view or opening the iMessage app itself. If anyone knows how to do this if possible please help

Comment: It's not possible

Comment: Great! Do you know of any third party applications that can do that or help me?

Comment: No because they do not exists. It's not possible without using the iMessage APIs. Check this out: https://developer.apple.com/reference/messageui/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti Of course it's possible. There are ways to send text messages and emails without showing a UI to the user.

Comment: @OrenEdrich What options have you researched? Options from a few years ago are still valid.

Comment: I have only seen pop ups

Comment: There are a number of services your app could use if _you_ want to send a text message to a provided phone number. The confirmation pop-up you see is needed only if you want to ask the _user_ to send a text using their phone number/account. Which one do you really need?

Comment: I'm not sure how create phone number, but using a phone number from a server would be ideal.

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti It is very possible.  I have built an app using smsbroadcast.co.uk which works very well.  If you're saying it's not possible to get a **free** service, then you may be right.